# dynamic item counter from SQLServer 2014 in web form for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, sql, counter, sql-server-2014

I'm new to this type of programming (management figures programming is programming... ugh), apologies in advance if my question seems convoluted or basic.

I'm creating a Windows Form App in Visual Studio 2015. I have it communicating and sharing with our SQL Server perfectly for every function but one. I'd like to place a "live" counter on the form, that updates a value every 3(or something) seconds. The counter's job would be to keep track of inventory being shipped out of our warehouse (just need to worry about getting that info from our SQL Server, which already has the capabilities, nothing before that) and display that information. Doesn't have to fancy, just accurate.

I've tried searching for answers for a while, but I'm not sure I'm using the right terms or maybe I've overlooked what I should be using for this process. I'm not looking for a complete solution, just a link to a site or some terminology help that describes what I need would be truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: are you searching for `Sql Query` ? or how to execute that `Query` against Db ?

Comment: I'm wondering how to create the actual counter object in VS2015, which would update itself continuously every "x" seconds to display the accurate count from the database. Would that be a sql query I create in the database, or a function of the object I create in VS2015 for the GUI? I've searched those topics but only found kind of generic answers, but I will search those topics again and see if I missed anything. Thank you for the help

Comment: if you are searching for mechanism how to run code in every `x` i can provide.

Comment: That would be so helpful! I would truly appreciate it! Thank you so much

Comment: i posted code, hope that will be useful, if not, give me a feedback and i will try to fix.

Comment: I am heading into work shortly, I will attempt to use the code you have generously posted here today and respond back hopefully in a day's time. Again, thank you!

Comment: no problem, glad if i can help ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following to run code every `interval` millisecond.

```
 public static void InitializeTimer()
 {
    var inerval = 3000;
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += keep_track_of_inventory_being_shipped;
    timer.Interval = inerval;
    timer.Start();
  }

  private static void keep_track_of_inventory_being_shipped(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
    //your code here
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I'm late responding, I got wrapped up in something. Can you explain what part of my code this snippet should be added to? A general direction is fine with me, like put the top half of your code above my tableadapter for whatever I want refreshed, then include the actual table adapter inside the keep_track_of_inventory_being_shipped method? Thanks so much, this is the last thing I need to do to finally be done with this project...

Comment: @shrug you are good to go, as you say put actual adapter inside `keep_track_of_inventory_being_shipped` method, after that you should call `InitializeTimer` method in order to get it work. if you struggle, please let me know.

Comment: @shrug Glad if helped