# C# recurrent task executing only once

Tags: c#

I would like BuildFeed to be running every second.
this code run it only once.

```
public class FeedDal{
        public FeedDal()
        {
          new Task(() => BuildFeed(), new CancellationToken(false), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();
        }

        private void BuildFeed()
        {
            //going here only once
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @SyxyMF Use `Timer` To run code permanently in every `x` second. [See answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701204/dynamic-item-counter-from-sqlserver-2014-in-web-form-for-visual-studio-2015/34722177#34722177)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why above code runs only once is that, well, you call it once.

In order to call some method permanently in every `x` second, you can use `Timer`.

Try following code.

```
public static void FeedDal()
{
  var inerval = 1000;
  var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
  timer.Elapsed += (o,e) => new Task(() 
  => BuildFeed(), new CancellationToken(false), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();
  timer.Interval = inerval;
  timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this solution, if `BuildFeed()` takes more than 1 second to run you may have multiple instances of it running at once.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only calling the function once. If you want it to call multiple times you will have to do something like this:

```
public class FeedDal
{
    public FeedDal()
    {
      while (true)
      {
          new Task(() => BuildFeed()).Start();
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
    }

    private void BuildFeed()
    {
        // Will go here once a second.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Jason.

Comment: @JasonHeddler Jason notice *to be running every second* in question.

Comment: @tchelidze Just modified the code so it will run once a second.

Comment: While true is dangerous and heavy,

Comment: @SexyMF, Clearly Jason likes to live dangerously