# Update Counter not updating my DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2015, counter

I'm creating a Windows Form App in Visual Studio 2015. I have it communicating and sharing with our SQL Server perfectly for every function but one. I'd like to place a "live" counter on the form, that updates a value every 3(or something) seconds. The counter's job would be to keep track of inventory being shipped out of our warehouse (just need to worry about getting that info from our SQL Server, which already has the capabilities, nothing before that) and display that information. Doesn't have to be fancy, just accurate.

```
public void InitializeTimer()
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3;
        timer.Start();
        timer.Elapsed += keep_track_of_inventory_being_shipped;
    }

    private void keep_track_of_inventory_being_shipped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshMyForm();
    }

    private void RefreshMyForm()
    {
        this.TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet.CMS);
    }
}
```

I had asked this question before ([dynamic item counter from SQLServer 2014 in web form for Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701204/dynamic-item-counter-from-sqlserver-2014-in-web-form-for-visual-studio-2015)) and I had thought I got it right but it was brought to my attention I was mistaken. So sadly I'm back... I have tried to modify the code with research on SO and other sources to get it working so this code looks different than the code in the URL I posted in the past. No dice.

Additional info: When the program first loads, "this.TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet.CMS);" loads the counter I want refreshed every few seconds (or minutes, whatever. I'll worry about that after the counter is working). It certainly does bring up the right count on program start, but I can't seem to get it to refresh at all. I am aware the last two methods may be overkill, but I decided to just leave it as is and ask. I started with the low interval just to check and see if it's updating. It's not :/ I don't get why there are no errors thrown up or why "this.TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet.CMS);" can update the count correctly from our database at start, but cannot be refreshed this way? If it's not asking too much, I'd prefer understanding this as well as suggestions to fix instead of just a fix.

The original solution posted by tchelidze was the one I previously went with, but I'm sure blame lies with me not implementing his suggestion correctly. I appreciate any help I can get, long time SO lurker here and I love the site/meta. Thanks all.

Comment: that's because you need to call the timer.Stop() when you get into `RefreshMyForm` then after the fill method has completed then call timer.Start() also the time is not accessible outside of this method `public void InitializeTimer()` you should drop a timer on the form and do it that way you should be calling your `RefreshMyForm` from the `timer1_Tick Event`

Comment: Also, for testing, you should make it 3000 (remember those are milliseconds and you don't want it refreshing 333 times per second).

Comment: --Stan: Heh thanks man, I think my lack of patience for this issue is showing.
--MethodMan: Son of a.... coming from a strongly typed language and still getting used to things like the toolbox and properties window etc etc. Thank you so much MethodMan, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @Methodman I'd like to mark your answer as correct/solved, but since it is in a comment I guess I can't? Just want to give you credit as I am grateful for your help.

Comment: @Shrug,  I have updated it to make it an answer so feel free to accept if you like..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you need to call the `timer.Stop()` when you get into `RefreshMyForm` then after the fill method has completed then call `timer.Start()` also the time is not accessible outside of this method `public void InitializeTimer()` you should drop a timer on the form and do it that way you should be calling your `RefreshMyForm` from the `timer1_Tick Event`